# Can the product rule be used in thie manner?

Tags: derivatives, chain-rule

I'm trying to understand the proof to Euler's formula and I keep getting stuck on one of the steps.

We start with:

$${\displaystyle e^{ix}=r(\cos \theta +i\sin \theta ).}$$

We will then assume that  this will hold true for *some* unknown values for $\theta$ and $r$, and try to reveal those values.

In the next step we take the derivative of both sides, so that:

$${\displaystyle ie^{ix}=(\cos \theta +i\sin \theta ){\frac {dr}{dx}}+r(-\sin \theta +i\cos \theta ){\frac {d\theta }{dx}}.}$$

....and this is where they lose me. $r(\cos \theta +i\sin \theta )$ is (as far as I can see) "not" a product of two functions, so why on earth are they using the product rule instead of the chain rule?

Link:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_formula#Using_power_series

Comment: The $r$ is being multiplied by the expression $(\cos(\theta)+i \sin(\theta))$, so it is a product of those two factors.  It seems product rule is the appropriate choice.  You're right though that there is a chain rule but it's just for the trig functions.

Comment: From the limked Wiki's entry : "for some r and θ depending on x". This means : $r(x)(cosθ(x) + isinθ(x))$

Comment: Sure but...they're treating $r$ like a "constant" here, since they're setting the derivative of $r$ to 1. 

I tried using the product rule on expressoins like $2(x+5)$ and that didn't work out, it only worked using the chain rule.

Comment: @Magnus, it doesn't look like they are treating $r$ like a constant, since above you've written the derivative of $r$ as $\frac{dr}{dx}$, not as a constant.  Product rule does work, even on expressions like $2(x+5)$.

Comment: @Carser 

If I use the product rule on $2(x+5)$ I end up with $2*(1)+1*(x+5)=x+7$. If I use the chain rule I end up with $2*1$ which is the actual answer?

Comment: The derivative of $2$ is $0$, so you actually end up with what I've described in my answer below.

Comment: @Carter so for the sake of clarity, can a constant then work as a "function" in this context?

Comment: Absolutely.  I'm sure at some time you have graphed a horizontal line, for example, $f(x)=5$ is a constant function where for any value of $x$, $y=5$.

Comment: From your comments, I think you've forgotten that the derivative of a constant is $0$. (I think they're treating $r$ as something that we don't yet know is constant.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$r(\cos(\theta)+i\sin(\theta)$ is indeed the product of two functions of $x$, $$r(x)$$ and $$g(x)=(\cos(\theta(x))+i\sin(\theta(x)))$$
So the product rule on these functions is
$$r'(x)g(x)+r(x)g'(x)$$
which gives what you have above,
$$
\frac{dr}{dx}(\cos(\theta(x))+i\sin(\theta(x))) + r(-\sin(\theta(x))+i\cos(\theta(x)))\frac{d\theta}{dx}
$$

Just to show the product rule with your example in the comments, given $$2(x+5)$$ the derivative using product rule is $$0\cdot(x+5)+2\cdot(1)=2$$

Comment: So the first expression should then be read as "the derivative of r (with respect to x) "times" $(cos(θ(x))+isin(θ(x)))$"?

Comment: It is the derivative of $r$ with respect to $x$ times $(\cos(\theta(x))+i\sin(\theta(x)))$, plus $r$ times ...

Comment: All right, I'll mark this down as the answer and work myself (arduously) throught the rest of the proof.

Comment: This wasn't part of my original question (and so I marked the answer as correct regardless) but...why do we take $r(−sin(θ(x))+icos(θ(x))$ "times" $dθdx$, haven't we already taken the derivative of the trig functions?

Comment: That's part of the chain rule on a trig function.  $\frac{d}{dx}f(g(x))=f'(g(x))g'(x)$.  In this case, when you do $\frac{d}{dx}\sin(\theta(x))$ you get $\cos(\theta(x))\frac{d\theta(x)}{dx}$